# Implementing android native side bar with React native navigation

Tags: android, react-native, sidebar, react-native-navigation

I am trying to implement native android side bar for my react native app with a special animation.
Very similar to the card effect in this library: https://github.com/shiburagi/Drawer-Behavior

The react side is using react native navigation to implement the side bar but onPress of hamburger is calling a native module in android.

My question is :

1. how to get current react view in android to attach to the drawer layout?
2. Is there anyway to get toolbar from react in android?